# Insert MySQL not working with var and insert empty row

Tags: php, mysql, insert, insert-into

I tried for long time understand what got wrong in this code:

I have two arrays that I want to put in the DB but the array can be changed any time. So it need to work dynamically.

All I get is an empty row without any data - but as string it work fine.

If I write the output string of query instead it works, but this way not:

```
$fields = $values = array();
                $j = 0;

                while ($j < mysql_num_fields($query)) {
                    $namee = mysql_fetch_field($query, $j)->name;
                    if(isset($AutoFill[$namee])){
                        if($AutoFill[$namee] == '?')
                            $values[]  = "'".mysql_real_escape_string("dopd")."'";//$_POST[$namee]
                        else
                            $values[] = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($AutoFill[$namee])."'";
                        $fields[] = "$namee";
                    }
                    $j++;
                }
                $fields = implode(",", $fields);
                $values = implode(",", $values);
// not working
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".$table_name." (".$fields.") VALUES (".$values.")");
// "INSERT INTO ".$table_name." (".$fields.") VALUES (".$values.")" => tostring working:
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO _users (user_name,display_name,password,email,activation_token,last_activation_request,lost_password_request,active,title,sign_up_stamp,last_sign_in_stamp) VALUES ('dopd','dopd','dopd','dopd','dopd','1409863484','0','dopd','New Member','1409863484','0')");
```

Answer (score 1):

This will not work because you cannot pass an array into a query.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".$table_name." (".$fields.") VALUES (".$values.")");
```

Try this instead:

```
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO ".$table_name." ('" . implode("','", $fields) . "') VALUES ('" . implode("','", $values) . "');" );
```

This will create a string out of your array that will pass into the SQL statement correctly. Do your implode within the query statement rather than above. Also, you were not wrapping the values in quotes individually, so you were getting one long string of values (ie: '1,2,3') instead of individually quoted values (ie: '1','2','3').

Comment: Also you should probably be using either mysqli or pdo for database connections. The standard mysql set of functions is deprecated for security reasons.

Comment: For $fields I believe you want to get rid of the single quotes around column names.

Comment: try
    $query = "INSERT INTO ".$table_name." ('" . implode("','", $fields) . "') VALUES ('" . implode("','", $values) . "');"

    echo $query;

Then manually run the query in phpmyadmin/sequel pro/etc. If it throws an error that should tell you what your problem is. This is a pretty easy way to debug queries in general.

Comment: thank you - after all i found the problem - there was no problem in my code except i forget declere $query varieble. Finally i have my dynamic queries as needed :) good weekend every body.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this was that the $query was not declered properly in the right place og scope.
The code work's great on any king and length of information from user.

thank you all - best weekend.